# XPath evaluate return anchor href if span in same row contains text

Tags: javascript, xpath

I want to return all **href** of the **anchor** tags if the **span** in the same **row** contains a specific **text**, but I am not sure how to write this XPath expression.

Below code is as far as I can get, and it will return me the **span**'s **innerHTML**.

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/m95wdg7f/

```js
var fruitsArray = [];
var nodesSnapshot = document.evaluate("//body/table/tbody/tr[*]/td[*]/span[contains(.,'apple')]", document, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null );
for ( var i=0 ; i < nodesSnapshot.snapshotLength; i++ ) {
    fruitsArray.push(nodesSnapshot.snapshotItem(i).innerHTML);
}
alert(fruitsArray);
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <td><a href="http://www.oranges.com">link</a></td>
  <td></td>
  <td><span>orange</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><a href="http://www.apples.com">link</a></td>
  <td></td>
  <td><span>apple</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><a href="http://www.bananas.com">link</a></td>
  <td></td>
  <td><span>banana</span></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td><a href="http://www.apples.com">link</a></td>
  <td></td>
  <td><span>apple</span></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

In my mind the solution should look something like this:

```
//body/table/tbody/tr[*]/td[*]/a//body/table/tbody/tr[*]/td[*]/span[contains(.,'apple')]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try any of the following `xpath` to find the `<a>` tag based on the `span` text.

```
//span[contains(.,'apple')]/parent::td/preceding-sibling::td/a
```

OR

```
//table//tr//td//span[contains(.,'apple')]/ancestor::td/preceding-sibling::td/a
```

OR

```
//table//tr//td//span[contains(.,'apple')]/parent::td/parent::tr/td/a
```

**DEMO 1:** 
[image]

---

**Updated xpath with or condition**

```
//span[contains(.,'apple') or contains(.,'banana') ]/parent::td/preceding-sibling::td/a
```

Comment: Thanks KunduK, all three worked perfectly for me. Now if I'd like to use an or statement, how could I return either **apple** or **banana**?

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat simpler expression:

```
//a/parent::*[contains(..,'apple')]/a/@href
```

This will select the two `http://www.apples.com` links.

Answer (score 1):

You can peel the same apple in different ways. However, the following is what I would stick to in such cases.

Try this out:

```
"//tr[.//span[contains(.,'apple')]]//a/@href"
```